# how to use same property value in all scopes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following is my view

```
  <div ng-if="isMultiChoiceQuestion()">
                <li class="displayAnswer" ng-repeat="choice in getMultiChoice() track by $index" ng-if="isNotEmpty(choice.text.length)">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkForSelection(choice.id)"
                            value="choice.text" disabled="true">
                      <span ng-class="getCSSClass($index, choice.id)">{{choice.text}}</span>
                </li>
              </div>

            <a class="weiter-link" ng-click="flipBack()">Zur Frage</a>

                <div ng-if="isMultiChoiceQuestion()">
                  <!--Changed ng-bind getScore() -> score -->
                      <h4>Bewertung speichern: <span ng-bind="getScore()"></span></h4>
                  <br />
                      <a class="weiter-link" ng-click="incrementOne()">Zur nächsten Frage</a>
                </div>
                  <div ng-if="!isMultiChoiceQuestion()">
                        <h3>Eigene Bewertung: {{score}}</h3>
                        <div class="ranger">
                          <input type="range" max="10" min="0" step="1" id="selfRanger" ng-model="score">
                        </div>
                        <a class="weiter-link" ng-click="submitScore(score)">Bewertung speichern</a>
                            <a class="weiter-link" ng-click="incrementOne()">Zur nächsten Frage</a>
            </div>
```

The above view create three scopes. one is for controller, second one is first div and second div is the third one. The problem is property called score in controller not get used in the second div.

How to make second div to use controller property than automatically created property?

JS

```
app.controller("QuizController", ['total', '$scope', '$rootScope',  'quizDataService',  'QAPointerChange', 'QAScoreList', function (total, $scope, $rootScope, quizDataService, QAPointerChange, QAScoreList) {

  $scope.getScore = function()
      {
          // Makes a call to getCurrentScore and returns a value
          $scope.getCurrentScore();
          return QAScoreList.getSpecificItemScore(QAPointerChange.getQAPointer());
      }
$scope.score = 0;

    $scope.submitScore = function (newScore)
    {
        QAScoreList.setSpecificItemScore(QAPointerChange.getQAPointer(), Number(newScore));
    }


      $scope.getCurrentScore = function()
      {
            $scope.score = QAScoreList.getSpecificItemScore(QAPointerChange.getQAPointer());
      }


}
```

This is not complete JS file. controller have all services responsible for making calls to service to fetch score and other data.

Comment: could you show us your js ?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO Added. thanks

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to use the same value on the childscopes created by `ngIf`? If yes, you could use `$parent.score` instead of `score` in your view. For displaying you wouldn't need to do that since the property would be inherited. But in this case you're editing the value within the childscope via `ngModel`.

Comment: I think your js need first some refacto:

You could add a return $scope.score; in $scope.getCurrentScore() and then remove the return in $scope.getScore(), it will help with a cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

If you use nested scopes, there are two ways:

### Dot rule

Do not use single variable like `$scope.score` but use `$scope.data.score` (your variable is in object which is in scope)

### Controller as

You do not assign variable to scope, but to controller (at the top of controller):

```
var self = this;
self.score = 5;
```

And in html:

```
<div ng-controller="QuizController as ctrl">
```

And you use it:

```
{{ctrl.score}}
```

---

### Update

The problem with slider being stuck:
You have `ng-bind="getScore()"` in your html so `getScore` is executed every $digest cycle. And every $digest cycle happens when there is need to redraw html (for instance when some scope variable changed). So:

1. when you slide the slider `$scope.current.score` changes
2. So $digest cycle starts
3. `getScore` is executed
4. `$scope.current.score` is changed with the value from `QAScoreList` in `getCurrentScore` function
5. Slider changes back to that value

It worked without dot rule because then both `$scope.score` and `ng-model="score"` were not the same variable (they were both in different scopes)

So it would be best to (I assume, that in "Bewertung speichern" you want to display the same value which is selected in range, if not you need to user some different variable name):

1. Change `ng-bind="getScore()"` to `ng-bind="current.score"`
2. Execute `$scope.getScore()` at the start of controller to get current value from service `QAScoreList`

Comment: dot rule makes data unchangeable in range input element. I have a lot of methods bounded to $scope so changing to controllerAs is difficult.

Comment: What do you mean that it's unchangable in range element? Did you use there also ng-model="data.score"? Try to init $scope.data = {}; at the beginning of the controller.

Comment: I did initialiate $scope.current = {}; then $scope.current.score = 0; then i set to ng-model="current.score". Now input[range] slider is not sliding anymore. It struck at 0.

Comment: I made fiddle based on yours: https://jsfiddle.net/t8vgjr7v/ It works fine. Don't you set current.score to 0 on $watch or something in controller which prevents slider to slide?

Comment: ng-model with dot rule is the culprit. If i remove the ng-model with dot rule it works as expected. If i use mg-model with just variable it works as well.

Comment: this is the link making input element struck $scope.current.score = QAScoreList.getSpecificItemScore(QAPointerChange.getQAPointer()). Can you please tell me how to make it work?

Comment: Aa, now I see  - you have ng-bind="getScore()" in your html so it runs getScore() function very often and than it sets the current.score from QAScoreList service even before you set it by sliding range. It would be better to ng-bind="current.score" and eventualy run getScore() once at start of controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120595/discussion-between-forethought-and-bartek-cichocki).

Answer (score 0):

if you call your function inside `ng-if` it will run the function only if the condition becomes true so the `getScore()` function does not get output for third div use `ng-init='getScore()'` in third div also

Comment: Thanks @Gopinath Shiva next time i remember to quote

Comment: @forethought have u finished or still confused